# Autocomplete textbox with 3 Columns

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a windows form with a textbox that works like a google search, I have a stored procedure that return a Registration in a list, I use the list in the `AutoComplete` method, The problem I'm facing is I want 3 Columns to show when the user enters the Registration I want to show the account and owner name in the dropdown so like this Registration|Account|Owner, but only searchable by Registration.

Here's my method for the StoredProcedure

```
public static List<string> GetAircraftRegistrationList()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("GCA");
    DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetAircraftRegistrationList");

    using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(dataReader["Registration"].ToString());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Here's my autocomplete

```
public static void LoadAircraft(TextBox autocompleteTextBox)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection list = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    autocompleteTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    autocompleteTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = list;
    autocompleteTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

    list.AddRange(Aircraft.GetAircraftRegistrationList().ToArray());
}
```

This works for the registration. How will I do Account and Owner to show in the Textbox as 3 columns

So i want this in the textbox:

Currently, no matter how you slice it, if you type "ab" you'll get a list of...

```
"Abacas"
"Abate"
"Abbrv."
```

With a multi-column option, you could type "ch" and get...

```
"Chris A.     | (656) 573-7834 | Blue"
"Christine B. | (656) 458-9823 | Purple"
"Charisma C.  | (656) 645-7823 | Green"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following query instead.

```
Dim com As New SqlCommand("Select Registration,Account,Owner from Registry where name like % " & txtbox.Text & " % ",conn)
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(com)
Dim ds As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds)
reg_drop.DataSource=ds.Tables(0)
reg_drop.DisplayMember="Registration"
reg_drop.ValueMember="Registration"
Account_drop.DataSource=ds.Tables(0)
Account_drop.DisplayMember="Registration"
Account_drop.ValueMember="Registration"
```